# SocketIO disconnects as transport close when is a ping timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io version 2.0.4, for both nodejs and the client, and have the following code for the internal ping function socketio uses:

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, {'pingInterval': 5000, 'pingTimeout': 10000});`

My problem is that when my client loses connection on the socket disconnect event sometimes it tells me that is due to transport close instead of ping timeout.

```
 socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
    console.log(reason)});
```

Is there anything that may cause my server think the user has close its connection?

Comment: It may be that the client noticed a timeout and dropped the connection on its end and then restablished a new connection.  If the transport is at least sort of working, then that disconnect would come through to the server as a normal disconnect.  The `reason` on the server would only be set to a timeout reason if it was the server who noticed the timeout.  Both ends can notice a timeout.

Comment: @jfriend00 The client has dropped and is about to reconnect. The thing is that this should cause a ping timeout and not a transport close

Comment: You don't seem to understand that if the client-side detects a problem or timeout, then it closes the connection from the client side and the disconnect reason in that case will be a transport close, not a timeout.  You will only get a reason of timeout if the server-side is the one that timed out.  Either side can cause a time out and a client-side timeout will show as a transport close on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 then why most of the times when the server can't reach the client it causes a ping timeout?

Comment: Because if the server finds a timeout, the it gets reported as such on the server.  But, if the client finds a connection problem first, it can't tell the server that.  All it can do is drop the connection so that's all the server knows.

Comment: @jfriend00 even if my client is the one detecting it first most of the times it causes a ping timeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168621/discussion-between-carlatr-and-jfriend00).